# How to disable my Geofence BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I'm following [Android's tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#define-a-broadcast-receiver-for-geofence-transitions) on defining a broadcast receiver for geofence transitions.

The BroadcastReceiver works, but I'd like to disable it inside the broadcast `onReceive()` method.

```
class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received broadcast")
```

The [Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#StopGeofenceMonitoring) says:

> You can stop geofence monitoring in the main activity used to add and
>   remove geofences; removing a geofence stops it immediately.

by using `geofencingClient?.removeGeofences()`.

However I need to remove my geofences or disable my broadcast receiver *inside* the broadcast `onReceive()` method.

Can this be done?

Comment: Did you give it try? I don't see why it shouldn't work

Comment: I don't know how to perform `geofencingClient?.removeGeofences()` inside my broadcast receiver. @ZohaibAmir

Comment: The steps that you followed in your activity, do tge same in on recieve. Create client, make getIntent() function and it should work.

Comment: For most of these libraries, you need Context, Broadcast can give you context so it would work.

Comment: Thanks I will try find the Geofence in `context`/`intent` @ZohaibAmir

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel same pending intent you set for receiver

AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, YOUR_PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
aManager.cancel(pIntent);

This is java code. you  have to write it in Kotlin.